# Android SQLite Database still error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've made aplication that entering 3 data to SQLite database, but still there is error 
when I click the ADD button that means to insert to database, Please help me to know the error guys :)

This is the following source of my application --> http://www.mediafire.com/?ur33rt6bdb8c1m3

thanks a lot, it really helps :)

Comment: Please post error message. Without knowing what is the error, it is hard to predict a solution.

Comment: for future reference you should check your logs for the exception and fix them.

Comment: oe, i will post the error for the next time. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    inputContent1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Problems_name);
    **inputContent2** = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jlh_kriteria);
    **inputContent2** = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jlh_alternative);
```

you had two same named variables. rename the last one to inputContent3
and you will be all set.